# Nested asp.net mvc 3 application in IIS 7 with broken relative links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have two asp.net mvc 3 applications.  The URL for one of the applications is supposed to be something like this: www.my-app.com.  The URL for the second application should be: www.my-app.com/my-second-app.

My approach has been to nest the second application inside the first one in IIS 7.  Everything works perfectly for the first application.  But relative links don't work in the second.  This is an example:

The link `<a href="/sample-controller/sample-action/id">sample text</a>` takes the user to `www.my-app.com/sample-controller/sample-action/id` instead of `www.my-app.com/my-second-app/sample-controller/sample-action/id`

I've tried adding a tilde (~) at the beginning of the `href` attribute.  But this returns paths relative to the folder where the view is located.

I've also tried using a virtual folder.

I'm wondering if this is the right approach to tackle this task? If so, is there a way to solve the problem with the relative links?

Comment: Why aren't you using MVC areas? (and `/path` on any configuration is an absolute path to the root (indifferent to the sub-folder/virtual path).)

Comment: Subdomains would be an ideal solution, a subdirectory is not ideal for app isolation.

Comment: @BradChristie: not using areas because the applications were developed separately.

Comment: @ChrisHardie: a subdomain would be ideal.  But it is not an option in this case.

Comment: @aspiring.algorist: You can host another web application in a parent mvc app as an area.

Comment: @BradChristie: Could you explain the benefit of using an area for this purpose?

Comment: @aspiring.algorist: Shields you from having to setup a virtual directory within the MVC site for your other MVC project, while providing unity in terms of routing.

Comment: @BradChristie: I'm not sure how to implement your proposed solution without moving files from the child application into the parent one.  I should also mention that both application have separate authentication (this is a requirement).  Using an area in the parent application would make it so that a person logged in to the parent would also have access to the child application, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since subdomains aren't an option for you, do the following:

- Create a virtual directory in your site, and point it at your nested application.
- When you need a URL in your nested application, you'll need to generate it dynamically so the runtime will resolve it properly for you.

If you are creating a URL to an action, use ActionLink: `@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "sample-controller", "sample-action")`

Alternatively, you can use the URL object: `<a href="@Url.Action("sample-controller", "sample-action")">My Link</a>`

Finally, if you want to point at a resource that isn't a controller action, use the tilde to have your application path resolved properly: `Url.Content("~/directory/page.html")`

Comment: I know that if I change all the links to use the framework's HTML helper things will work.  What I'm trying to avoid is going through all the links that don't use the helper and updating them.  We also have links that we build using the TagBuilder that would have to be updated.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of any way to get around it, if you have already hard-coded links that will fail when you move your app.